# How to pass an Activity reference to my own component

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-activity

I crated a datetime component but it's constructed automatically (I have it in a XML layout and I don't want to create it manually) but I need to pass a reference to an `Activity` in order to create dialogs. How can I achieve that?  I tried a setter after `findViewById` but it's not a good solution...

```
public class DateTimeComponent extends RelativeLayout {

    private Activity activity;

    public DateComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        // rest ommited
        initFields();
    }

    private void initFields() {
        dateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateEditText);
        dateEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity.showDialog(DATE_PICKER_DIALOG);
            }
        });

        timeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timeEditText);
        timeEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity.showDialog(TIME_PICKER_DIALOG);
            }
        });
    }

    // rest ommited

    public Dialog getDatePickerDialog() {
        int year = selectedDateTime.get(YEAR);
        int month = selectedDateTime.get(MONTH);
        int day = selectedDateTime.get(DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(activity, onDateSetListener, year, month, day);
    }

    public Dialog getTimePickerDialog() {
        int hour = selectedDateTime.get(HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = selectedDateTime.get(MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(activity, onTimeSetListener, hour, minute, true);
    }

    private final OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // do something
        }
    };

    private final OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // do something
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: You may pass the reference of Activity/Context to the DateTimeComponent via constructor.

Comment: you can use context for this purpose

Comment: @Akki context does not have `showDialog()` method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may help you:

**Option 1:**

```
public class DateTimeComponent extends RelativeLayout {
    private Activity activity;

    public DateTimeComponent(Activity act){
        activity = act;
    }

    public void someListener() {
        activity.showDialog(...);
    }

}
```

**Option 2:**

```
public class DateTimeComponent extends RelativeLayout {

    public void someListener(Activity act) {
        act.showDialog(...);
    }

}
```

**Option 3:**

```
...
    private Activity activity;

    public DateComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        activity = (Activity) getContext();

        // rest ommited
        initFields();
    }

...
```

Comment: But I don't create the component, I'm using `DateComponent component = (DateComponent) findViewById(R.id.dateComponent)`

Comment: I updated my question... I can't use your second option either because I initialize all listeners in the component itself.

Comment: The third option is working. One last question: can I be sure that the given context can always be cast to `Activity`?

Comment: yes, as long as you are referencing your custom class or views from Activity, you can cast it

Answer (score 1):

Two ways -

1. Create a constructor that accepts a Context parameter, and have a (private?) class variable of type Context which you can use whenever.
2. Add an extra Context context parameter for every method that will be needing it. In some cases you may need to make that final.

Answer (score 1):

The context your constructor receives IS an Activity. So, you can cast it to it. For example like this

```
MyActivity a = (MyActivity) getContext();
```

P.S. You do not need to store activity in your own field:

```
private Activity activity; // not needed
```

it is already stored inside and can be obtained by http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()

**PROOF**

Custom text view:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setText(Integer.toString(System.identityHashCode(context)));
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setText(Integer.toString(System.identityHashCode(context)));
}


}
```

Activity:

```
public class ContextActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    textView.setText( Integer.toString(System.identityHashCode(this)) );
}
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<com.inthemoon.incubation.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The codes diplayed are identical.

Comment: I'm curious - `The context your constructor receives IS an Activity` do you have any reference for that?

Comment: The `Activity` class is a descendant of `Context`. I determined experimentally, that activity is passed to constructor in simple cases like described one. I am a newbie and and can't guarantee that it is always so. `Context` has multiple implementations so in some cases they can be used.

Comment: This is not a proof. It only shows that this is the **current** implementation on **your** current platform.

Comment: By emphasizing "my platform" you mean that it is not works on yours?

Comment: No. I mean that it's not a proof. It makes sense that the context is the Activity, but I have seen no requirement for such behavior.

Comment: Documentation may be just incomplete, I don't expect it is perfect. They just probably forgot to state about what is context, because I can't imagine what else they can pass as context in case above. Sorry my thoughts might because I often work with open source software, where apidocs are often neither complete nor 100% correct. Probably this is wrong if the developer is Holy Google :)